# How to center a Window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

What's the easiest way to centre a `java.awt.Window`, such as a `JFrame` or a `JDialog`?

Comment: The title should be "in Swing" not "in Java", it would be more clear that way.

Comment: @Joe `setLocation()`, `setLocationRelativeTo()` and `setLocationByPlatform()` or all AWT, not Swing.  ;)

Answer (score 278, accepted):

From [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20080921040824/http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/center-dialog-box-frame-or-window-in.html)

> If you are using Java 1.4 or newer,
>   you can use the simple method
>   setLocationRelativeTo(null) on the
>   dialog box, frame, or window to center
>   it.

Comment: As @kleopatra said on another answer, setLocationRelativeTo(null) has to be called after pack() in order to work.

Comment: As explained below, setLocationRelativeTo(null) has to be called after any call of pack() or setSize().

Comment: @Eusebius Odd, I followed a tutorial that made me set it before `pack()` and it put the topleft corner of the frame at the center of my screen. After moving the line to below `pack()` it got properly centered.

Comment: Well pack() sets the correct size based on the contents and layout, and you can't centre something unless you know its size, so it is indeed odd that the tutorial had you packing it after centering it.

Comment: You are so right, @user1433479!! thanks for your comment!!! 

Answer (score 73):

This should work in all versions of Java

```
public static void centreWindow(Window frame) {
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Comment: I know that this is pretty old but this works fine, provided the frame size is set before calling this function

Comment: Yep, make sure the size is applied before (using pack() for example)

Answer (score 42):

`setLocationRelativeTo(null)` should be called after you either use `setSize(x,y)`, or use `pack()`.

Comment: You're right. It needs to have setSize() call before.

Answer (score 27):

Note that both the setLocationRelativeTo(null) and Tookit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() techniques work only for the primary monitor.  If you are in a multi-monitor environment, you may need to get information about the specific monitor the window is on before doing this kind of calculation.

Sometimes important, sometimes not...

See [GraphicsEnvironment javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) for more info on how to get this.

Answer (score 21):

On Linux the code

```java
setLocationRelativeTo(null)
```

Put my window to random location each time I launched it, in a multi display environment.
And the code

```java
setLocation((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width  - getSize().width) / 2, (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - getSize().height) / 2);
```

"cut" the window in half with placing it to the exact center, which is between my two displays.
I used the following method to center it:

```
private void setWindowPosition(JFrame window, int screen)
{        
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] allDevices = env.getScreenDevices();
    int topLeftX, topLeftY, screenX, screenY, windowPosX, windowPosY;

    if (screen < allDevices.length && screen > -1)
    {
        topLeftX = allDevices[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x;
        topLeftY = allDevices[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().y;

        screenX  = allDevices[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width;
        screenY  = allDevices[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height;
    }
    else
    {
        topLeftX = allDevices[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x;
        topLeftY = allDevices[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().y;

        screenX  = allDevices[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width;
        screenY  = allDevices[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height;
    }

    windowPosX = ((screenX - window.getWidth())  / 2) + topLeftX;
    windowPosY = ((screenY - window.getHeight()) / 2) + topLeftY;

    window.setLocation(windowPosX, windowPosY);
}
```

Makes the window appear right at the center of the first display.
This is probably not the easiest solution.

Works properly on Linux, Windows and Mac.

Comment: Taking multi screen environments into account is the only correct answer, otherwise the screen where the window appears could be somehat random or the window is centered between both screens.

Answer (score 6):

I finally got this bunch of codes to work in NetBeans using Swing GUI Forms in order to center main jFrame:

```
package my.SampleUIdemo;
import java.awt.*;

public class classSampleUIdemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /// 
    public classSampleUIdemo() {
        initComponents();
        CenteredFrame(this);  // <--- Here ya go.
    }
    // ...
    // void main() and other public method declarations here...

    ///  modular approach
    public void CenteredFrame(javax.swing.JFrame objFrame){
        Dimension objDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int iCoordX = (objDimension.width - objFrame.getWidth()) / 2;
        int iCoordY = (objDimension.height - objFrame.getHeight()) / 2;
        objFrame.setLocation(iCoordX, iCoordY); 
    } 

}
```

OR

```
package my.SampleUIdemo;
import java.awt.*;

public class classSampleUIdemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        /// 
        public classSampleUIdemo() {
            initComponents(); 
            //------>> Insert your code here to center main jFrame.
            Dimension objDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int iCoordX = (objDimension.width - this.getWidth()) / 2;
            int iCoordY = (objDimension.height - this.getHeight()) / 2;
            this.setLocation(iCoordX, iCoordY); 
            //------>> 
        } 
        // ...
        // void main() and other public method declarations here...

}
```

OR

```
    package my.SampleUIdemo;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class classSampleUIdemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
         /// 
         public classSampleUIdemo() {
             initComponents();
             this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // <<--- plain and simple
         }
         // ...
         // void main() and other public method declarations here...
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

below is code for displaying a frame at top-centre of existing window.

```
public class SwingContainerDemo {

private JFrame mainFrame;

private JPanel controlPanel;

private JLabel msglabel;

Frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  //headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
 /* statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);    
  statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
 */ msglabel = new JLabel("Welcome to TutorialsPoint SWING Tutorial.", JLabel.CENTER);

  controlPanel = new JPanel();
  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  //mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
 // mainFrame.add(statusLabel);

  mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
  mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  mainFrame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  

  centreWindow(mainFrame);
```

}

```
public static void centreWindow(Window frame) {
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
    frame.setLocation(x, 0);
}


public void showJFrameDemo(){
 /* headerLabel.setText("Container in action: JFrame");   */
  final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(300, 300);
  frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());       
  frame.add(msglabel);

  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        frame.dispose();
     }        
  });    



  JButton okButton = new JButton("Capture");
  okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  //      statusLabel.setText("A Frame shown to the user.");
      //  frame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                getScreenSize();
        final BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(
                new Rectangle(screenSize));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScreenCaptureRectangle(screen);
            }
        });
        mainFrame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
     }
  });
  controlPanel.add(okButton);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

}
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
new SwingContainerDemo().showJFrameDemo();
```

}

Below is the ouput of above code-snippet:[image]

Comment: `frame.setLocation(x, 0);` seems to be wrong - shouldnt it be `frame.setLocation(x, y);` instead?

Comment: x denotes the length of x axis and y denotes the length of y axis. So if you make y=0 then only it should be at top.

Comment: So `int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);` exists in code only to show that you can also center in vertical axis? Ok, I thought you just forgot to use it, sorry for trouble.

Comment: No problem. Deem! Its Great to talk to you.

Answer (score 3):

frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

Full example:

```java
public class BorderLayoutPanel {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton btnLeft, btnRight, btnTop, btnBottom, btnCenter;

    public BorderLayoutPanel() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Border Layout Example");
        btnLeft = new JButton("LEFT");
        btnRight = new JButton("RIGHT");
        btnTop = new JButton("TOP");
        btnBottom = new JButton("BOTTOM");
        btnCenter = new JButton("CENTER");
    }

    public void SetLayout() {
        mainFrame.add(btnTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.add(btnBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainFrame.add(btnLeft, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainFrame.add(btnRight, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainFrame.add(btnCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //        mainFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        //        or
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        //take up the default look and feel specified by windows themes
        mainFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //make the window startup position be centered
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(mainFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following doesn't work for JDK 1.7.0.07:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

It puts the top left corner at the center - not the same as centering the window.  The other one doesn't work either, involving frame.getSize() and dimension.getSize():

```
Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
frame.setLocation(x, y);
```

The getSize() method is inherited from the Component class, and therefore frame.getSize returns the size of the window as well.  Thus subtracting half the vertical and horizontal dimensions from the vertical and horizontal dimensions, to find the x,y coordinates of where to place the top-left corner, gives you the location of the center point, which ends up centering the window as well.  However, the first line of the above code is useful, "Dimension...".  Just do this to center it:

```
Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( (int)dimension.getWidth() / 2, (int)dimension.getHeight()/2 ));
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setLocation((int)dimension.getWidth()/4, (int)dimension.getHeight()/4);
```

The JLabel sets the screen-size.  It's in FrameDemo.java available on the java tutorials at the Oracle/Sun site.  I set it to half the screen size's height/width.  Then, I centered it by placing the top left at 1/4 of the screen size's dimension from the left, and 1/4 of the screen size's dimension from the top.  You can use a similar concept.

Comment: Neither does the other one.  These codes put the top left corner of the screen in the center.

Comment: -1 can't reproduce - or more precisely: happens only if the setLocationRelative is called _before_ sizing the frame (by pack or manual setSize). For a zero-sized frame it's top-left corner is the same location as .. its center :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's something really simple that you might be overlooking after trying to center the window using either `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` or `setLocation(x,y)` and it ends up being a little off center.

Make sure that you use either one of these methods ***after*** calling `pack()` because the you'll end up using the dimensions of the window itself to calculate where to place it on screen. Until `pack()` is called, the dimensions aren't what you'd think thus throwing off the calculations to center the window. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Example: Inside myWindow() on line 3 is the code you need to set the window in the center of the screen.

```
JFrame window;

public myWindow() {

    window = new JFrame();
    window.setSize(1200,800);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // this line set the window in the center of thr screen
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    window.setLayout(null); // disable the default layout to use custom one.
    window.setVisible(true); // to show the window on the screen.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the calls is important:

**first** -

```
pack();
```

**second** -

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class SwingExample implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Create the window
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello, World!");
        SwingExample.centerWindow(f);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10000, 200));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void centerWindow(JFrame frame) {
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(insets.left + insets.right + 500, insets.top + insets.bottom + 250));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code center the `Window` in the center of the current monitor (ie where the mouse pointer is located).

```
public static final void centerWindow(final Window window) {
    GraphicsDevice screen = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getDevice();
    Rectangle r = screen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    int x = (r.width - window.getWidth()) / 2 + r.x;
    int y = (r.height - window.getHeight()) / 2 + r.y;
    window.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this also.

```java
Frame frame = new Frame("Centered Frame");
Dimension dimemsion = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setLocation(dimemsion.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dimemsion.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
```

Comment: What about multiple monitors?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to modify [Dónal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144950/5645656) to accommodate a multiple display setup:

```
public static void centerWindow(Window frame) {
    Rectangle bounds = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
    Dimension dimension = bounds.getSize();
    int x = (int) (((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2) + bounds.getMinX());
    int y = (int) (((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2) + bounds.getMinY());
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually frame`.getHeight()` and `getwidth()` doesnt return values , check it by `System.out.println(frame.getHeight());` directly put the values for width and height ,then it will work fine in center. eg: as below

```
Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - 450)/2);
int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - 450)/2);
jf.setLocation(x, y);
```

both 450 is my frame width n height

Comment: -1 a frame's size is zero before ... sizing it :-) Preferably by pack, or at least by manually setting its size to anything else than zero _before_ calling setLocationRelative will allow its internal correct calculation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Donal's* answer, I would like to add a small calculation that makes sure that the Java window is perfectly at the center of the window. Not just the *"TOP LEFT"* of `the window is at the center of the window`.

```
public static void centreWindow(JFrame frame, int width, int height) {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

        // calculate perfect center
        int perf_x = (int) x - width/2;
        int perf_y = (int) y - height/2;

        frame.setLocation(perf_x, perf_y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple answer for Java NetBeans:

Right click on the JFrame, go to properties, then go to code and select generate center option.

Look image for reference:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFXbL.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push center of your app window, you can do solved to follow.

```
int x = (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width) - getSize().width) / 2;
int y = (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height) - getSize().height) / 2;
setLocation(x,y);
```

getSize() function is app frame size...
getScreenSize() is your pc screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This is minimalistic variant which centers a frame on screen defined by parameter

```
private void centerThisWindow(int screen) {
    GraphicsDevice[] screens = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    int i = (screen >= screens.length || 0 > screen) ? 0 : screen;
    Rectangle r = screens[i].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    setLocation(((r.width - getWidth()) / 2) + r.x, ((r.height - getHeight()) / 2) + r.y);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!